# Jquery template not accepting dash (-)

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have following code. where i'm using the Jquery template but it is not accepting - (dash) in class-no. I'm getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: no is not defined`. Is there any solution for this issue with jquery template.

```
var json = [{"class-no":"12","marks":"500","marks1":"200","marks2":"300"},{"class-no":"11","marks":"200","marks1":"300","marks2":"400"}]

$.template('kList','<tr title="${class-no}"><td>${marks}</td><td>${marks1}</td><td>${marks2}</td></tr>');  

for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){   
    $.tmpl('kList',json[i]).appendTo("#table1")
}
```

Comment: Most likely that needs to be wrapped in quotes. Currently it's trying to subtract `no` from `class`

Comment: can you resolve this issue i know it will work if ill use console.log(json[0]["class-no"]); but to make it posssible in templet

Comment: @NickTomlin, please check over the entire question for errors, and not just the title.

Comment: Try changing hyphens to underscores all through. If it still doesn't work, then suspect something else.

Comment: you mean to change hyphens in templet to underscore or you want me to change in json

Comment: I would assume they mean both.  It appears that the template library is evaluating anything within ${}, so it's trying to do math instead of returning the value.

Comment: Yes, in both. Change every occurrence of `class-no` to `class_no`.

Comment: the Json is coming from the API is it possible to remove the hyphens by some means or methds in the json itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just feed a custom function in the option parameter while template invocation and use the function in the template as,

here `classNo` is a custom function and it access the object property with string notation.

```
$.template('kList','<tr title="${$item.classNo()}"><td>${marks}</td><td>${marks1}</td><td>${marks2}</td></tr>');  

for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){   
    $.tmpl('kList',json[i], { 
        classNo : function(){ 
            return this.data["class-no"];
        }
    }).appendTo("#table1");
}
```

hope this helps.